# Writing unit tests for camel routes in a SpringBoot application - getting messageCount 0

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, camel-test

I am trying to write unit tests for a camel route - its for importing and processing a file

```
from(fullImportFTP)
        .routeId(STUB_FILE_DOWNLOAD_ROUTE_ID)
        .onException(Exception.class)
        .handled(false)
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, STUB_IMPORT_ERROR_CODE)
        .end()
        .log("Processing  Stub file:[${header.CamelFileName}]")
        .to(ROUTE_TO_MACE);

from(ROUTE_TO_MACE)
        .routeId(STUB_FILE_IMPORT_ROUTE_ID)
        .onException(Exception.class)
        .handled(false)
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, STUB_IMPORT_ERROR_CODE)
        .end()
        .onException(IOException.class)
        .maximumRedeliveries(routesConfig.camelMaximumRetries).redeliveryDelay(routesConfig.camelRedeliveryDelay)
        .handled(false)
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, STUB_IMPORT_ERROR_CODE)
        .end()
        .split().tokenizeXML(ITEM).streaming()
        .process(processor)
        .to("log:route.StubRoute?level=DEBUG")
        .end()
        .log("Stub file sucessfully processed:[${header.CamelFileName}]");
```

And below is the unit test:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class CamelRouteTest {
    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:success_result")
    private MockEndpoint successResultEndpoint;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "direct:mock-import-stub-download")
    private FluentProducerTemplate producer;

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;

    @MockBean
    RestTemplate restTemplate;


    private static final String MOCK_IMPORT_STUB_DOWNLOAD = "direct:mock-import-stub-download";
    private static final String TEST_STUB_FILE_LOCATION = "src/test/resources";

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        camelContext.getRouteDefinition(STUB_FILE_DOWNLOAD_ROUTE_ID).autoStartup(true).adviceWith(camelContext,
                new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
                    @Override
                    public void configure() throws Exception {
                        replaceFromWith(MOCK_IMPORT_STUB_DOWNLOAD);
                        interceptSendToEndpoint("log:route.StubRoute?level=DEBUG").skipSendToOriginalEndpoint().to(successResultEndpoint);
                    }
                });

        camelContext.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFileDownloadRouter() throws Exception {
        File file = new File(TEST_STUB_FILE_LOCATION + "/Stub_11092018_162149_59642501.xml");
        successResultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        producer.withBody(file).withHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, "Stub_24102018_162149_59642501.xml").send();
        successResultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();                                                                                                                                                                                                
    }
```

I always get the message count as 0. Here is the ERROR

> java.lang.AssertionError: mock://success_result Received message
>   count. Expected: <1> but was: <0> Expected :<1>  Actual   :<0>

What am I doing wrong here? I have 2 routes as you can see - the first one actually goes to the second one, so in the unit tests should I have 2 routes too? I haven't added 2 routes because if I debug I can see that it actually goes through the processor and returning the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: you are using **[AdviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html)**, so you should put the annotation `@UseAdviceWith` on your testclass. Otherwise the automatic start of the Camel context and the route advice could overlap.

For the missing message on the Mock: Perhaps **your test just asserts too early**. I guess the producer does not block while the message is processed, but the MockEndpoint assert follows immediately after sending the message. Right after sending the message the received message count is still 0.

To check if waiting helps, you could insert a Thread.sleep(). If it works, you should **get rid of the Thread.sleep()** and replace it with a [Camel NotifyBuilder](http://camel.apache.org/notifybuilder.html)

Just saw another point. The final `to()` in your `interceptSendToEndpoint` chain points to the MockEndpoint instance variable. I think this should point to the MockEndpoint URI, i.e. `.to("mock:success_result")`

And even one more: you get the first route to advice with `getRouteDefinition(STUB_FILE_DOWNLOAD_ROUTE_ID)` but in this advice block you advice **both routes**. That is probably the reason for your problem. The second route is not adviced and therefore your mock is not in place. You have to advice the second route in its own advice block.

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    camelContext.getRouteDefinition(STUB_FILE_DOWNLOAD_ROUTE_ID).autoStartup(true).adviceWith(camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            replaceFromWith(MOCK_IMPORT_STUB_DOWNLOAD);
        }
    });
    camelContext.getRouteDefinition(STUB_FILE_IMPORT_ROUTE_ID).autoStartup(true).adviceWith(camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            interceptSendToEndpoint("log:route.StubRoute?level=DEBUG").skipSendToOriginalEndpoint().to("mock:success_result");
        }
    });

    camelContext.start();
}
```

Comment: I have added the @UseAdviceWith annotation and put a wait, but it still fails unfortunately..

Comment: changed the interceptEndPoint too to the URI , fails again.. Don't know if this is of any use but I can see this in the logs - "camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint    : Asserting: mock://success_result is satisfied" before the routes shutdown and the error message.

Comment: Yeah, this is logged when the assertion is checked. It does not mean that it is satisfied, it is like "Asserting now if mock is satisfied..." and then the error message is the result.

Comment: Just to isolate the problem. Can you replace the log-statement with the mock-endpoint statically, i.e. change the code the way the interceptor should do and disable the interceptor? If it works then, the interceptor has a problem. If it still not works, the Mock endpoint does not work correctly.

Comment: Just saw another one: your advice block references the first route. Therefore the second route is not adviced and your mock endpoint not in place.

Comment: how do I do that? should I have 2 references?

Comment: You have to do two separate adviceWith blocks, see in my extended answer